# App will not connect to Firebase Storage- Will not open, No errors

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I was going through a tutorial to create a voice recorder which will then upload the recording to Firebase. I watched the tutorial many times and made sure the app is connected to Firebase; however, the app will not open right now most likely due to this issue. I'm pretty new to Java programming. Can someone please provide me with some guidance? Thank you

```
package bfb.ess.myapplicationbfb;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class speakp extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mRecordBtn;
    private TextView mRecordlabel;

    private MediaRecorder mRecorder;

    private String mFileName = null;

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Record_log";

    private StorageReference mStorage;


    private ProgressDialog mProgress;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recordpage);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mRecordlabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recordlabel);
        mRecordBtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName +="/recorded_audio.3gp";

        mRecordBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    startRecording();

                    mRecordlabel.setText("Recording Started ...");

                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    stopRecording();

                    mRecordlabel.setText("Recording Stopped ...");
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;

        uploadAudio();
    }

    private void uploadAudio() {



        mProgress.setMessage("Uploading Audio ...");
        mProgress.show();

        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Audio").child("new_audio.3gp");

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mFileName));

        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                mProgress.dismiss();

                mRecordlabel.setText("Uploading Finished");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: `however, the app will not open right now most likely due to this issue` Which issue?

Comment: Not being connected to Firebase.

Comment: I don't see the firebase auth. Did you sign in ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Firebase console and update read and write rules for storage

You can look into the Google Firebase Sample: [Storage Sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/storage)

Please check the URI of audio file if its proper. Because I guess lastPathSegment of uri is getting faulty.

By Default:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<name_of_app>/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Update it to:

```
service firebase.storage {
      match /b/<name_of_app>/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
          allow read;
          allow write;
        }
      }
    }
```

**NOTE:**
This update will allow you to store the data even if you are not authorised.
It is only for development purpose because it can cause security issue of accessing the data without getting authorised.
So take care when uploading the app to play store, update this parameter and change according to your requirement.

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
  }
} ////// Ran the app and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the read and write rules for storage in your firebase console,

Go to Firebase console, select storage 
Click on the Rules tab

By Default:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Change to:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

as Mohom.R said

NOTE: This update will allow you to store the data even if you are not authorised. It is only for development purpose because it can cause security issue of accessing the data without getting authorised. So take care when uploading the app to play store, update this parameter and change according to your requirement.